# Syntax error with PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my first time using PL/SQL. I am getting an error on the UPDATE statement below. Though I don't think there is something wrong with the UPDATE statement, but rather the IF condition, that is just above the UPDATE statement. The error I'm getting in SQL Developer, says: `"Error(20,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * @ % & - + / at mod remainder rem then    <an exponent (**)> and or || multiset The symbol "then" was substituted for "UPDATE" to continue."`

So basically what I want to do is this:

```
if(current_pwd != oldUserPwd1 || current_pwd != oldUserPwd2) {
   Make the update ...
}
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SUPDATEWORD(
   current_pwd Users.Password%TYPE,
   current_uid Users.UID%TYPE   
)
is
  oldUserPwd1 VARCHAR(255);
  oldUserPwd2 VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN  
  SELECT X1.PASS1
  INTO oldUserPwd1 
  FROM OLDUSERPASSWORDS x1
  WHERE current_uid = x1.UID;

  SELECT X2.PASS2
  INTO oldUserPwd2 
  FROM OLDUSERPASSWORDS x2
  WHERE current_uid = x2.UID;

  IF current_pwd <> oldUserPwd1 OR current_pwd <> oldUserPwd2
    UPDATE ISOUSERS SET Password = current_pwd; 
    UPDATE OLDUSERPASSWORDS SET PASS1 = current_pwd AND PASS2 = oldUserPwd1 AND DATELASTCHANGE = SYSDATE;
  ELSE
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'This exception means success');
  END IF;

END SPUPDATEPASSWORD;
```

Comment: Aside from the syntax error (in answer below), you should really consider storing HASH values rather than the passwords directly. A web search will reveal many, many articles about why you don't want to store passwords directly in databases.

Comment: I am already storing the hash, and not password in clear text :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `THEN`:

```
IF current_pwd <> oldUserPwd1 OR current_pwd <> oldUserPwd2 THEN
```

Answer (score 1):

OR

```
if current_pwd != oldUserPwd1 or current_pwd != oldUserPwd2 then
   Make the update ...
end if;
```